# Stylized math like rendering?

Tags: rendering, shader, mathematics, shading, font-rendering

How can I render plots and graphics that mimic how mathematicians draw diagrams?

For example Look at this shirt:

[image]

The diagrams represent 2D and 3D shapes, however they have characteristics of human drawings. The curves are not perfect and exhibit lot's of noise and waviness that a computer rendering would normally not have.
If you know any papers regarding this topic, please add them as reference to your answer.

As a side note and perhaps somewhat off topic: Is there a C++ library that can do tex rendering onto textures?

Comment: Read: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11350/xkcd-style-plots

Comment: "*Is there a C++ library that can do tex rendering onto textures?*" If you can generate pixel data from TeX, then you have everything you need to generate a texture from TeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check [matplotlib-cpp](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp). You'll find a "funny-looking xkcd-styled example" in the README.

I also saw xkcd related entries on matplotlib's Python documentation. So, it should be available in Python too. However, I did not use these libraries myself. I just stumbled upon matplotlib-cpp while I was looking for a plotting library for C++.

Comment: This is neat and I will try it, although I am more interested in the technique itself.

i.e. I am looking for the algorithm not the software. But I can take a peek at the implementation of that package, thank you.